# why can't I append to div in ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have a `<div id="container"></div>` in my `examples.hbs`. In my controller I have an init function:

`init: function(){
   $('#container').append("test 123");
}`

But this doesn't append anything. However if my div container is in my `index.html` I do see 'test123' being appended. That makes me believe that the init function is being called before the template has rendered.

So I guess my question is what is the proper way to append things on initialization?

Note: I am using Three.js which creates a webGLRenderer, and I am just appending this renderer (ie canvas) to the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`init` will be called on your controller well before the template has loaded. You need to put the code into the `didInsertElement` method on your view (or bind another method to the event).